# Submersion and local section.

Tags: differential-topology

A surjective submersion (surmersion) between smooth manifolds
$
\pi : M \rightarrow B
$
is a fiber bundle if it is proper (Ehresmann theorem).

In particular, there always exists local sections of $\pi$. One can try to glue this local section in a global one, but there are obstructions.

The questions is:

*What are the obstruction for the existence of an immersion $\iota :B \rightarrow M$ such that $\pi \circ \iota$ is a covering of $B$ ? 
In particular the case where the total space and the base space are compact.*

Any reference is welcomed too.

A bit more general: What can we get by gluing local section ? When is it possible to get a possibly immersed compact manifold by gluing multi-valued section (in the case where the base space is compact).

Comment: Immersion or section? Or immersive section?

Comment: I was thinking about a multi-valued section, I should reformulate this